# How to use the posterior predictive distribution for checking a model from PyMC

Tags: python-3.x, pymc

I am trying to understand how to use a posterior predictive check (`PPC`) after building a bayesian model using the `PyMC` library. I've never done this before and I don't quite understand how I should proceed...

Concretely, I would like to be able to generate a large number of samples from the posterior predictive distribution and compare them to the sample I used to build the model, using a simple criterion: the maximum value of the samples.
I refer for this to Ben Lambert's presentation video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDPJnV9vcHs) (see at 8:15) where he presents the following graph, which perfectly expresses what I would like to get:

[image]

So I built a simple model, where I gave myself a sample of 20 values that are supposed to come from a normal distribution with mean `mu` and standard deviation `sigma` that I am trying to estimate. (note that I gave myself a `mu` and a `sigma` to generate the sample which is the basis of the model).

I then built the code referring to various examples and included the `sample_prior_predictive` and `sample_posterior_predictive` instructions according to the information given by the `API — PyMC 5.1.1 documentation` (https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/stable/api.html) in the `“samplers”` paragraph
The code works (on my computer) and does not generate errors.

On the other hand, I am looking but I cannot find how to concretely use the posterior predictive distribution and generate the histogram of the maximum values of the samples drawn from this distribution.

Well, I am training myself in Bayesian analysis and have a hard time manipulating and using PyMC outputs which I am not yet familiar with; If you could give me some pointers...

The code used is:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
import arviz as az

np.random.seed(63123)
data = np.random.normal(loc = 600, scale = 30, size = 20)

with pm.Model() as model:
    
    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    mu = pm.Uniform('mu', lower = 0, upper = 2000)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower = 0, upper = 100)

    # Likelihood of observations
    lkd = pm.Normal('likelihood', mu = mu, sigma = sigma, observed = data)
    
    # Expected value of outcome (WHAT IS THE USE ???)
    weights = pm.Normal('weights', mu = mu, sigma = sigma)
    
    # Inference data
    idata = pm.sample()
    
    # Predictives
    pm.sample_prior_predictive(samples=500, var_names=None, random_seed=None, 
                               return_inferencedata=True, 
                               idata_kwargs=None, compile_kwargs=None)    
    
    pm.sample_posterior_predictive(idata, 
                                   var_names=None, sample_dims=None, random_seed=None, 
                                   progressbar=True, return_inferencedata=True, 
                                   extend_inferencedata=True, predictions=True, 
                                   idata_kwargs=None, compile_kwargs=None)
```